# List clients subscribed to a certain topic in Mosquitto server

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto, publish-subscriber

So that is the general question, but I'll provide the scenario here.

I'm running Mosquitto server to provide mqtt comm between esp relay modules ([Sonoff from Itead](https://www.itead.cc/sonoff-wifi-wireless-switch.html)) and [Home Assistant](https://home-assistant.io/).
Most of the time, it works just fine. Each module has its own topic, and there are as many "light" configurations in HASS as modules, so they can be controlled from the web frontend by individual toggle buttons.

I've experienced, though, inconsistent state situations where the light is actually on and the toggle in HASS is shown as off (and the opposite situation as well).
By inspecting logs I've found that Mosquitto is not publishing certain messages to HASS (which should be subscribed to all module state topics). More specifically, given 4 modules and its corresponding state topics (`state/sonoff_xx/POWER`), HASS seems to be subscribed only to modules 2 and 4 topics, but not 1 and 3. The following is the expected behavior for module 4, the same can be verified for the other working module, but publishing to HASS is missing for the other two.

```
Jun 15 19:22:46 nas mosquitto[9486]: Received PUBLISH from sonoff4 (d0, q0, r1, m0, 'stat/sonoff4/POWER', ... (2 bytes))
Jun 15 19:22:46 nas mosquitto[9486]: Sending PUBLISH to home-assistant (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'stat/sonoff4/POWER', ... (2 bytes))
```

This is not a question regarding HASS and the relay modules, but it is about how to dig into the status of MQTT Server that is supposed to have certain clients subscribed but, by looking at the logs, it has not.

Answer (score 7):

No, you can no get list of which clients are subscribed to what out of mosquitto.

What is most likely here is that HASS is not subscribing rather than mosquitto not publishing to a subscribed client.

You can get mosquitto to log each time a subscription request is which made which you could then use to build a list.

```
log_type subscribe, unsubscribe
```

This will log all which clients subscribe/unsubscribe from what topics.

Comment: I'm already logging all levels (`log_type all` in `mosquitto.conf`), actually I've checked the subscribe entry by connecting from a console while having `journalctl -f` running. I couldn't find, though, entries about HASS subscriptions because that might happened days ago and journald is not configured as persistent, so I had at hand only current boot. That's the reason why I hoped to inspect Mosquitto status.

Comment: Shouldn't you focus on QoS level. My guess is that the messages sent from the nodes (Sonoff units) are being sent using QoS=0 meaning it is sent only once. Not reliable in that sense. I would try to bump this value until I find a a good level. Switch states should be using QoS 1 or 2 in my opinion. Sensor values which is ok to miss one or two once in a while should use QoS 0.

Answer (score 3):

You can Enable mosquitto log for all
and subscribe to the log you will find messages that you can decode for every client action like connecting, disconnecting, subscribing and publishing even errors.

you will set

```
log_dest topic
log_type all
```

in mosquitto.conf
then you will subscribe to

```
$SYS/broker/log/#
```

Comment: I tired this approach Subscribing and publishing events are not shown